# How to check for uniqueness on existing data in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models, unique

`validates :uniqueness => true` is the quick and effective way to enforce uniqueness before saving a model.

Is there an easy way to check uniqueness of existing data? Iterating through each item and comparing it to the others seems so clunky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I most often do this with direct SQL - but here's a Rails (version 3, using arel) way of doing it - use the group operation and get a count of the field you want.

e.g. if I have a bunch of Events - and I wanted to get a count of events that have unique titles:

```
Event.group(:title).count
```

That returns a ActiveSupport::OrderedHash of the title and the count found.  You can then do a [select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Hash.html#method-i-select) on the hash to filter out the list of tiles.  e.g.

```
Event.group(:title).count.select{|title,count| count >= 2}
```

That gives you the titles that you can go back and do something with, finding each and deleting one, etc.

You can also do a ["having" operation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having) (which I do in raw sql) e.g.

```
Event.group(:title).having('count(title) >= 2')
```

which is:

```
SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` GROUP BY title HAVING count(title) >= 2
```

in SQL

The nice thing about that is you get the full object list that you can enumerate over without going back to the db and delete items, print timestamps, whatever.

It's just a little harder to look at in the console because the full record is loaded and not just a hash of the titles and counts.